# Can I create a Web-based demo on an android device and deliver it offline?

Tags: android, offline, demo

I've created a Web-based demo that lives on my laptop PC so I can deliver it offline. Can I port that demo to an Android-based tablet?

As my question probably makes all too clear, I've never owned a tablet of any kind, and I know nothing about Android -- but I'm ready to buy an Android tablet if I can store my own Web-based demo on it and run it locally (offline). Is that possible?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an application that browse offline web pages that ship with the application inside a webview for example

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the android version and browser used in any particular tablet, but on standard android you don't have to create any application as the standard browser would be enough.

Just load your files onto the SD card and in the browser open for example file:///sdcard/myapp/index.html